# Contacting a Potential Supervisor about Funding (after agreeing on project)

Tags: phd, advisor, funding, email

I am in the process of contacting a potential supervisor to pursue a PhD in his group. We have agreed on the project and that I am a good fit for the project. However, there remains the funding issue. The professor is only granted funding for a UK citizen (since it's a university in the UK) from the department. But since I am an overseas student (the fees are double that of UK/EU citizens) he has to make a case to convince the department to fund me. I emailed him once, a week after our agreement, asking about updates regarding this situation. I got an update but no definitive yes-no answer and I am still waiting for more information. He said he would contact me when he has more information. But it's been more than 10 days since our last contact and I haven't received anything. Should I email him again? If so, what should I mention in the email (without seeming too pushy)?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't push unless I had another option to consider and might need to back out of acceptance for another position. Ten days isn't a lot of time to move a bureaucracy.

However, if you need to write to him on another legitimate matter you could add a note at the end whether anything has developed about funding. If your acceptance is contingent on funding he should know that.

Comment: Then, how long should I wait to contact him again? @Buffy

Comment: @Mkw, if you have decisions to make about the position, then contact him soon enough to enable those decisions. But if it is just your wish to know, I'd keep waiting. If you have doubts about whether it will happen, explore what other options you may have.